# How can I make Google Sheets count number of cells in one column based on condition in another column

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, countif

[My example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1twb2pBrYZCXOcPHbH2CcRT-_u8xFALR-CM13OYDwdY0/edit?usp=sharing)

In column A different models are listed.
In column B status are listed marked with "kaput".

I'm trying to count the number of certain models, UNLESS they're listed as "kaput".

In this case I want to count all models including "11", "C733", "C771".

It's a challenge since "11" or "221133" or "model 11" sometimes is regarded as text.

I have tried countif/s, regex, arrayformula and sum - what can I do better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=countifs(index(regexmatch(A2:A&"";"11|C771|C733"));true;B2:B;"<>kaput")
```

[image]

Comment: This is just perfect and way more simple than all my failed attempts. Thank You for taking the time.